# What does -t|--tag[=[]] mean in Docker?

Tags: docker

In Docker-build in the man page, the argument tag is mentioned.

```
-t|--tag[=[]]
```

What does [=[]] mean exactly?

Comment: Anything in square brackets is optional. Nested brackets mean optional parts within optional parts. Empty brackets means you can put anything in there that won't be parsed as another flag

Answer (score 1):

The tags can be unset, which is why the entire option is nested in square brackets. The syntax looks a bit strange to me, and may not follow the syntax used in other man pages, but when set, tag can be set to an array of strings. You do this by passing the tag option multiple times:

```
docker build --tag myapp:v1 --tag myapp:latest .
```

So my reading of the inner brackets in the man pages is it's indicating the option accepts multiple values.

Comment: You are correct that the whole argument spec being enclosed in square brackets is supposed to mean the argument can be repeated. Acting like the `*` operator in regular expressions. See [man for man](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/man1.html) `[expression] ... entire expression within [ ] is repeatable. `

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the `man page`, you mean [this ArchLinux page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/docker/docker-build.1.en):

[image: ArchLinux]

If you look at [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), you can see it just references `-t`:

[image: -t]

The extra brackets you see in the ArchLinux page simply denote the *usage* of `-t` / `--tag`. The outermost brackets (only the right-hand one is shown in your example) denote separation from the other commands, grouping the `-t` and `--tag` flag together for the same command result (note the pipe). The middle brackets denote that there are options for the flag. The innermost brackets denote that the array of valid values for the options. In the case of `--tag`, there are no valid options, so the array is empty.

This can (arguably) be more readably expressed as: `--tag [TAG_NAME]`

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. The flexibility to have an argument like `--tag=` is there in case you have situations where commands are build dynamically. Perhaps you want to employ the 80:20 rule and not add code which ensures there is no "=" for boolean arguments. You wouldn't know that is possible with your suggested format.

Comment: I do not understand, how you can have this regular expression and form "-t mytag:latest" with it?

Comment: Also, empty brackets doesn't mean no valid options. It means you can put anything in there that doesn't look like the start of another argument

Comment: @Griffin How is it possible to derive -t mytest:latest from that? Is the equal sign not necessary here?

Comment: @David it is kind of like undefined behaviour in C. Perhaps the person who implemented the argument parser in their program allows you to omit the "=" (which is admittedly usually the case - again for greater flexibility). But if the documentation specifies that you should use a "=", then it is safer to do so.